# SQL Server Developer Clustering Limitations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi we're building out some test clusters in Azure, using Developer edition of SQL Server 2016. However with no firewalls between the two nodes, both nodes in same subnet, all tcp/ip settings enabled and sa permissions on both servers we're unable to connect using SSMS (management studio),  what I'm trying to understand is are there any limitations with creating AlwaysOn Availabiity groups using SQL Developer 2016? Getting the following error

```
Mcrosoft SQL Server, Error 5 "Access is Denied"
```

However I can log onto the instances on both machines locally using ssms, but not across the network.

Think it might be a limitation on the sql server edition?

Thanks and sorry if this seems a bit random :)

Comment: Developer edition has all the same features as Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to SQL server on VM from a local machine. you have to not only open 1433 port for the VM on the portal, but also do you need to set up the firewall inside of the VM machine. Make sure you have the inbound 1433 port opened as below:

[image]